# Sum days between differing date/times progromatically

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query that works perfectly fine, by summing the values for a day.

```
SELECT CAST(fldDateTime AS DATE) AS DayValue, SUM(fldValue) AS Val
FROM [dbo].[Data.tblMeterData]
GROUP BY CAST(fldDateTime AS DATE)
ORDER BY DayValue
```

The problem I have is that I needed to have the data greater than midnight and up until midnight of the next day. To test I can do this I tested the following code, which helped me deal with the first lot of values that do not have a full day.

```
 DECLARE @a DATETIME
 DECLARE @b DATETIME

SET @a = CAST('2016-03-21 00:01:00' AS DATETIME)
SET @b = DATEADD(SECOND,-86399 ,@a)
SELECT @a AS a, @b AS b

SELECT CAST(fldDateTime AS DATE) AS DayValue, SUM(fldValue) AS Val
FROM [dbo].[Data.tblMeterData]
WHERE fldDateTime BETWEEN @b AND @a
GROUP BY CAST(fldDateTime AS DATE)
ORDER BY DayValue
```

The problem with this is that I do not want to loop through dates, as I have thousands of ID's that I need to process in this way.I cannot include midnight for the first date as the first data is recorded after midnight and the final daily reading is at midnight the following day e.g.

```
    Date > '2016-03-20 00:00:00' AND <= 2016-03-21 00:00:00
```

**How can I do what I need to do the following:**

- Find the first date for an ID and move up to the first midnight of the following day and repeat this for all following days.
- Sum these values so that they are greater than midnight and up to midnight of the next day.

Comment: I think it would be good to give some sample data and output, i'm not clear on what you want

Comment: What is the best way to share the table data and some of the results on here

Comment: When you say I needed to have the data greater than midnight and up until midnight of the next day, do you mean 1/2/2016 00:00:00 = 1/2/2016 11:59:59 or one second more meaning 1/3/2016 00:00:00?

Comment: Just provide some sample data as text and what you would expect the results to be. like create table #temp (dt datetime) insert into #temp ... some values... expected output would be X

Comment: Link to the file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8wa646wnwqs4l9/TestData.csv?dl=0 the date time column needs formatting for date time.

Comment: Table: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data.tblMeterData](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [tblMeterData_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [fldDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [fldValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 [fldBatchId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: If we imagine yesterday, I need the data that is greater than `20/12/2016 00:00:00` and up to `21/12/2016 00:00:00`. I need to sum for that day every row of data that exists in the database for a given ID.

Comment: your drop box link formatted the dates as times only. What output columns are you expecting? If I am reading correctly you want ID, Date, Sum (includes data for Date and Date + 1).

Comment: The datetimes are every 30 minutes on the half hours, e.g. 20/12/2016 00:00:00, 20/12/2016 00:30:00, 20/12/2016 01:00:00, 20/12/2016 01:30:00 etc...As for output you are correct that it is ID, Date and SUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the requirements is you are looking for the sum of a value group by meter ID and date, but for each date we also want to include the next day's values. This means each value would count in the sum for its day and the previous day.

Code:

```
--generate test data
declare @tblMeterData table (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [tblMeterData_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [fldDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [fldValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
        [fldBatchId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL);

insert  @tblMeterData (tblMeterData_Id, fldDateTime, fldValue, fldBatchId) values
        (18, '2016-12-19 23:59:59', 1.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-20 00:00:00', 2.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-20 00:30:00', 3.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-20 01:00:00', 4.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-20 01:30:00', 5.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-21 00:00:00', 6.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-21 00:30:00', 7.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-22 00:00:00', 8.0, newid()),
        (18, '2016-12-23 00:00:00', 9.0, newid()),
        (19, '2016-12-20 00:00:00', 10.0, newid());

--select    * from @tblMeterData order by ID;

--main query
with cte as (
        --0:00:00 reports on previous day
        select  *, cast(dateadd(S, -1, fldDateTime) as date) group_date
        from    @tblMeterData

        union   all

        --duplicate all records to also group on previous day
        select  *, cast(dateadd(D, -1, dateadd(S, -1, fldDateTime)) as date) group_date
        from    @tblMeterData
)
select  tblMeterData_Id, group_date, sum(fldValue) sum_value
from    cte
group   by tblMeterData_Id, group_date
order   by tblMeterData_Id, group_date;
```

Results:

```
tblMeterData_Id group_date  sum_value
18      2016-12-18  3.00
18      2016-12-19  21.00
18      2016-12-20  33.00
18      2016-12-21  24.00
18      2016-12-22  9.00
19      2016-12-18  10.00
19      2016-12-19  10.00
```

Comment: I have put the data in a text file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7dcemgbaqa37d4/TestData.txt?dl=0

Comment: I tried your query and it doesn't sum correctly, you will see in the file that the first sum from `2016-03-20 00:30:00` to `2016-03-21 00:00:00` should be 662.98. It's close so it is a good start for me to play with it, thank you.

Comment: It looks like I missed the > 0:00:00 part and my result is >= 0:00:00. I will put up a new version in a few minutes that deals with that.

Comment: I moved everything back 1 second before picking the group date which will put midnight values to recording on the previous day.

Comment: For anyone reading this at a later date, please note that I wasn't 100% clear on the requirements but this helped solve the problem. See The OrangeGoblin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (       

SELECT *, CAST(DATEADD(S, -1, fldDateTime) AS DATE) group_date
FROM [dbo].[Data.tblMeterData]              

)
SELECT  tblMeterData_Id, group_date, SUM(fldValue) sum_value
FROM    cte
GROUP   BY tblMeterData_Id, group_date
ORDER   BY tblMeterData_Id, group_date;
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: Oh you just wanted current date with the midnight moved to previous day. Sorry!

Comment: You did solve the main problem so i give you the correct answer